# How to handle exception between spring REST web services

Tags: java, rest, exception, spring-boot

I have two web services based on Spring boot, REST and MVC. The first service(DesignService) project calls the second service(UserService) project passing a email as parameter and gets the user object(User.java) back. How can I handle if no user is found.

DesignService project

repository.java

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
getUser(String email){
    restTemplate.postForObject("url for User service",email,User.class); //calls User service for Object[1]
}
```

UserService

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping()
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@RequestBody String email){
    User user = repository.getUser(email); //return a user object from DB
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user);[2]
}
```

Repository.java

```
public User getUser(String email){
//query db for user 
return user; //what to return if no user is found [3]
}
```

1. what to do at point [3] if user not found .throw exception or return empty user object?
2. what to do at [2] any excpetion handling / http status code / ... ??
3. how do I handle these exceptions at [1]. I dont think checking for  user as null is a good idea.

* excuse me if am wrong in some syntax as I have typed it directly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Return null, or if you're on Java 8, an empty Optional
2. If no user is found, return an empty Response with a 404 (NOT_FOUND) status, i.e.

> new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

3. Catch org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException

Finally, why are you POSTing to an endpoint that only returns a resource? You should be doing a GET, and from the looks of it, your request mapping should only support GET (method = RequestMethod.GET).

Comment: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND denotes that the service itself is no available contradictory to the No User found . I may mistake in the Design service that user not found instead of page not found. kindly correct me if I am wrong.    I do will use a GET method :-)

Comment: I disagree; 404 means that the resource at a particular URI is not found, not that the website is down. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: the link says 404 as  "The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI". Request URI means the url [link](http://service/getUser ).Am I right ?

Comment: yep. don't forget what the "r" stands for in uri.